# Get values inside arrays without the square brackets

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to access data inside a list, but I cannot access it using the square brackets []. The getTalonPaie is a function that call the get method from the HttpClient service and it returns me an observable containing multiple values. The problem is when I was to put it in my array, it is not returning me multiples arrays but one weird empty list with data in it.

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.listeTalonPaie = Array<number>(1);
    const test = [1, 2, 3];

    this.listeIndividus = this.indS.listeIndividu;
    this.listeIndividus.forEach(ind => {
      // The function below is returning me an observable (from httpClient.get()) containing 
      // multiple objects and I want to add them in my array. I used the push method because
      // I need a dynamic array since the number of objects returned by the observable is not
      // static. 
      this.rcs.getTalonPaie(ind.id)
        .subscribe( data => {
              this.listeTalonPaie.push(data.heures);
              test2.push(data.heures);
        });
     });
     // The output is [empty] (i) 
     // 1: 25
     // 2: 40
     // 3: 36
     // length: 4
     // __proto__ : Array(0)
     console.log('listeTalonPaie ', this.listeTalonPaie);
     // The output is [null]
     console.log('listeTalonPaie ', JSON.stringify(this.listeTalonPaie));
     // The output is undefined
     console.log('Un element ', this.listeTalonPaie[0]);
     // The output is (3) [1, 2, 3]
     console.log('test ', test);
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it. So if you think there is a better method tell me.

Answer (score 1):

So `data` is an array and you're pushing that array into `this.listeTalonPaie` (also an array), so you end up with a nested array `[[1,2,3]]`.

Not sure what your intent is but you might want to use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or spread instead of push.

```js
this.listeTalonPaie = [...this.listeTalonPaie, ...data.heures];
```

---

> my console.log() was printing me undefined data.

The `subscribe` method is asynchronous so `console.log` is running before your `data` callback gets invoked. Here's a tiny simulation of it:

```js
// mock subscribe implementation
const subscribe = (callback) => {
  // wait half a second then invoke callback with some data
  setTimeout(() => callback([1,2,3]), 500);
}

let result = [];

subscribe(data => {
  result = [...data];
  console.log('1:', result);
});

console.log('2:', result); // <-- called before 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the subscription syntax. I think you should make a new function below and provide it to the subscription.

```
this.rcs.getTalonPaie(ind.id)
    .subscribe( data => {
          this.listeTalonPaie.push(data.heures);
          this.logDataList(data)
    });
 });


logDataList(data: any) { console.log(data) };
```

If it possible you can pull data in `ngOnInit` and then you have an easy way to get data from your variable when you run `onSubmit` function

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was no actual problem. In fact, my list works, but my console.log() was printing me undefined data. If someone could explain me why I get undefined data in the console instead of the real value I would be happy !